# How do you properly translate "aware"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Both "aware" and "conscious" can be translated as "conscience" in French, but "conscious" and "aware" have different meanings (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09602010500484581).

If we consider that "conscience" is the French equivalent of "conscious" or "consciousness", what could be a (near) exact translation of "aware"/"awareness"?

**EDIT** (after having seen user @Dimitris comment and answer):

The article I pointed out highlights the differences in English between "conscious" and "aware" (mind/spirit/mental-state wise) which are often used interchangeably. The author describes awareness as a subset of consciousness, and "aware" doesn't seem to have a proper nuanced equivalent in French. As a native French speaker, the only translation I could think about is awake = éveillé. But I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: I think that the difference between *conscious* and *aware* is much fuzzier in English than the author of your article believes. [This webpage](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-consciousness-and-vs-awareness/) describes *consciousness* as a subset of *awareness*, and not the other way around.

Comment: I can't imagine a single example where either "aware "or "conscious" (both adjectives) would be translated as *conscience* (a noun). If you use words without context, an adjective will remain an adjective and a noun a noun.  Instead of pointing to an article explaining the difference between two English words, if you have difficulty finding the right word in French, maybe you could use both words in a sentence and suggest a translation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen sensibiliser/sensibilisation?

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/awareness.html

Quite often the translation of French (English) words/idioms to English (French) counterparts depends upon the context.

[image]

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/aware/563967

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. The article I pointed out highlights the differences in English between "conscious" and "aware" (mind/spirit/mental-state wise) which are often used interchangeably. The author describes awareness as a subset of consciousness, and "aware" doesn't seem to have a proper nuanced equivalent in French. As a native French speaker, the only translation I could think about is awake = éveillé. But I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: @Lawris No reason to apologize. As I said to my comment: 'Welcome to FSE'. After having asked 800 (!) questions I comfirm that you did the right choice to post your question here:-)!

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! :-)